# Calculate the remainder of $11^{2020} / 7$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I tried to get a pattern by doing

$11^1 / 7 = 1 , r=4$

$11^2/7 = 17, r=2$

$11^3 / 7 = 190, r=1$

but the numbers keep getting larger and larger and I think this is not the way to go about this problem. Can someone please explain the correct way on how to deal with these problems?

Comment: [Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) with $11^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$.

Comment: **Hint:** If $11^{3}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, then $11^{m}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$ for any $m$ that is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$11^3\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$

$$11^{2020}\equiv 11^{3\cdot 673}\cdot 11 \equiv (1)^{673}\cdot {11}\equiv 4 \pmod 7$$